# How to get selection event from all EditText areas

Tags: android, service, textview, copy, selection

I'm trying provide a Android **Service** that makes possible to do some actions when user make selection on any **TextView** (messages,books etc). But I don't know how to get this events outside my **Activity**.
I can add listener for specific **TextView**

```
mTextView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback
```

But I want get event (like `setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback`) from all TextViews.
I hope for your help!

Comment: Maybe it would be easier if you provide your custom implementation of `TextView` inheriting from original one an use that implementation everywhere in your app where you use `TextView`. That would work if the actions which you want to perform are constrained to `TextView` on which user make selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying provide a Android Service that makes possible to do some actions when user make selection on any TextView (messages,books etc).

This is not possible. Each application handles its own action modes, context menus, etc. when text is selected.